# Bash: How to prevent overwriting the same line when outputing?

Tags: bash

I have this

```
while read -r line
do
   echo -e "$line\r"
done <<< $keys
```

Where $keys, if printed as it is displays 30k rows.

When doing echo as above I get only one line as output.

I need to filter every line and then output it.

1. Why is that happening (overwriting)
2. How can I prevent it to happen?

Comment: Use More Quotes! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use More Quotes

```
while read -r line
do
   echo -e "$line\r"
done <<< "$keys"
```

observe the quotes in `<<< "$keys"`

Look:

```
$ printf -v keys '%s\n' "key one" "key two"
$ echo $keys
key one key two
$ # Oh dear
$ # Now with quotes:
$ echo "$keys"
key one
key two

$ # Yeah :)
$ # Same with a here string:
$ while read line; do echo "$line"; done <<< $keys
key one key two
$ # Oh dear :(
$ # Now with quotes:
$ while read line; do echo "Read: $line"; done <<< "$keys"
Read: line one
Read: line two
$ # Done \o/
```

---

In this post, you have learned:

- to use more quotes,
- to use more quotes,
- to use more quotes,
- to use more quotes,
- to use more quotes,
- and to use more quotes.

Now remember,

### Each time you forget quotes, God kills a kitten

Comment: Yes, using more quotes makes it work :)) Thanks, good lesson!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the `\r` in your `echo` command.

It will be solved replacing it to:

```
echo "$line"
```

It is also important to note that to call the variable you'd better use `"$keys"` to keep its format.

All together:

```
while read -r line
do
   echo -e "$line"
done <<< "$keys"
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem. +1 (gniourf_gniourf answered first)

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to just `echo -ne "$keys"` ?

Comment: @Michael well technically I was 12" faster but no problem :) Glad it is solved to you.

Comment: @ruakh mmm I don't really know. `man echo` says that `-n` is for `do not output the trailing newline`, so it depends on what is the intention.

Comment: @fedorqui: Well, O.K., or `echo -e "$keys"`. (I was assuming `"$keys"` already had the trailing newline, hence the `-n`.) Either way, my point is that there's no reason to split `$keys` by line and then print each line normally, when you can just print `$keys` to begin with.

Comment: @ruakh I guess this it is just a small piece of a script in which the OP must be processing each line differently. Something like: `this is line 1`, `this is line 2`, and so on. Otherwise it is completely overcomplicated, yes :D

Comment: @fedorqui: I was assuming the `\r`, which you removed, was relevant to the purpose of the OP's script. (Of course, that could still be achieved in a single statement, by writing something like `echo -e "${keys//$'\n'/$'\r\n'}"`.)

Comment: Thanks for feedback! I needed to go each line in order to parse it specifically.